# require().server. Require with a dot in the statement

Tags: node.js, module, require

```
                var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
```

I came across this in some NodeJS code and I don't believe I have ever seen a require with a dot in the statement like this ever before. Is the dot perhaps loading just a portion of the websocket module or is there another meaning to it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the object exported by `module.exports` you are taking the object referred by `server` key.

If you look [at the code](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/lib/websocket.js#L2) you could see that it is requiring [this module](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/lib/WebSocketServer.js)